# Can I use 'strategically situated' in this way?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, difference

> Singapore is strategically situated off the southern tip of the Malay peninsular, neighboring to Indonesia and
>   Malaysia with close proximity to major international shipping routes, and geographically located ca. 1° north of the equator with
>   a tropical climate.

Can I use 'strategically situated' in this way? I am not really sure, because the location of Singapore is not a result of choice. 'Strategically ' sounds to me that it is a rational choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my now-deleted comment,...

> Singapore ***just happens to be*** located somewhere which is ***of strategic importance*** (in principle, it's the *location* that IS "strategic", rather than it having been a "strategic choice" to establish it there, though obviously the two "meanings / causes" overlap to some extent).

Sure - in *some* contexts, ***to be situated / placed / located*** could be the result of a deliberate "act of placement". And in OP's *specific* context, at least *some* element of that "volitional act" sense must inevitably apply. But unless you believe in a deity fully engaged in "micro-management" of the universe, that could hardly apply to...

> [Ceres was discovered in 1801 and is situated in the Asteroid Belt.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and%20is%20situated%20in%20the%20asteroid%20belt%22)

Who knows? Perhaps in our space-faring future, people will have reason to say *Ceres is **strategically** situated in the Asteroid Belt*.